# Using com.fasterxml.jackson and org.codehaus.janino in the same maven project

Tags: java, maven, jackson, fasterxml

Is it possible to use com.fasterxml.jackson and org.codehaus.janino on the same project, I want to use com.fasterxml.jackson for good, but my project needs Spring 1.5.10. despite having exclusions for jackson-annotations in fasterxml, the error persists

My maven POM file for looks like this already

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

However when starting the application I get a spring error `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` this is easily fixed by removing the fasterxml package.